# TextField with optional Int value is not changed in SwifUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the textField with optional Int value.
But when I changed the int value, the textField is not being updated.
The code is like below.

```
@State private var amount: Double?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField(value: $amount, format: .number) {
            Text("$0")
        }
        Button("reset") {
            reset()
        }
    }
}

private func reset() {
    amount = nil
}
```

I want to textField value to nil when the button is tapped.
But the above code is not working.
What could be the problem?

Comment: I think you should edit your code to fix `Text("$0")` to `Text("Amount")` because you are getting a lot of bad answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying the hardcoded string `"$0"` - you aren't actually using the closure value. You need to use string interpolation to display the actual closure value.

You also need to decide what to display in case `amount` is `nil`. Below example displays `0` when `amount` is `nil`.

```
TextField(value: $amount, format: .number) {
  Text("\($0 ?? 0)")
}
```

Using named closure arguments helps you avoid similar issues in the future, since if you don't use the named closure argument, you get a compiler warning.

You could also display the `String` `"nil"` in case `amount` is `nil`:

```
TextField(value: $amount, format: .number) { amount in
  Text("\(amount?.description ?? "nil")")
}
```

Comment: That Text label isn't used for anything though

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the variable `amount` to nil because `amount` is a `Double` You'll get this error : 'nil' cannot be assigned to type "Double"
And this code `Text("$0")` isn't correct. If you want to display `amount`, you have to use `Text("\(amount)")`

```swift
struct PostSwiperView: View {
    @State private var amount: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(value: $amount, format: .number) {
                Text("\(amount)")
            }
            Button("reset") {
                reset()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func reset() {
        amount = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: That Text label isn't used for anything though